# Is there a smart solution for handling a lot of functions in liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, liquibase

I have a lot of functions(500+) in the project. It’s spring boot + PostgreSQL.
How to configure liquibase to include all functions from directory and update them if needed?

For example

1. I modify a few functions inside.
2. Liquibase run “CREATE OR REPLACE …”(for each function) on app startup.
3. This way I don’t need any new changeset.

Are there any drawbacks of it?
I don’t like to copy paste 500 changesets.

Comment: Put each function into a SQL script, then use `sqlFile` to include them with `runOnChange="true"`

Comment: This doesn’t works when I change content in attached sqlFile.

Comment: Yes it does - we use this method all the time. Did you add the `runOnChange` attribute?